# save removed html tags on a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

How to REMOVE html tags from xlsx sheet cells and SAVE them may on another dataframe to be MERGED later ?

I've searched about that till now for two days but I found nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Just a note , I'm using pandas on processing.

Comment: Add  sample of your excel and expected output

Comment: @AjayTomGeorge here is an example 26  Assuming this is the only css on the page, how wide will the box be when its rendered .box{         Width: 100px;         Height: 50px;         Padding: 5px;         Border: 1px solied red;         Background-color: red; }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          61b7baf7-6818-4250-9e19-3373d8ca5179

Comment: 27  What will the font size of the link be? <div class="primary">   <a href="#" class="link">Home</a> </div> <style>  .primary a {   font-size: 16px; }  div a.link {   font-size: 20px; } </style>

Comment: @AjayTomGeorge the expected output is the newly "TRANSLATED" to any language I want with the same mentioned html tags ... But there is a point , that the translation tool doesn't accept html tags or any coding symbols .. that's why I need to hide them when starting translation process.